# How to enable GridViewCommandColumn sorting on a DevExpress ASPxGridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

The other columns are sortable. 
The command column does not trigger a callback to sort the grid.

How can I enable GridViewCommandColumn sorting so that I can create my own custom column sort for that column?

Comment: `GridViewCommandColumn`s allow users to perform actions like Edit and Delete. Why would you want to perform sorting on this type of column?

Answer (score 0):

GridViewCommandColumn does not contain any data. So u can't sort a command column in ASPxGridview.

Comment: Of course you can. Assume it contains checkboxes. You can sort them as putting the checked ones first or last.